# Git workflow for non-sequential installation of features. Why git / GitHub sees two commits with the same code as different?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I work for a customer which requests different features, wants to test them on a test server,  but usually does not request their installation in the production server in a sequential way. See an example of the usual workflow in the drawing I attach: in this example, the customer requests feats. A, B, and C, but then he decides to install B first, later A ...

[image]

I have the following branches:

- A "develop" branch, with the code that runs on the test server
- A "master" branch, with the code that runs on the production server
- Feature branches

Due to the non-sequential requests of features, I simply cannot merge "develop" into "master". Thus, I merge the feature branches both to the "develop" and "master" branches. This creates merge commits A, B, A', B'.

But at some point in time, I will need to base new features on old ones: for example, let's imagine in my drawing that I now need to develop a feature (feat. D) based on both feats. A and B. If I branch for feat. D from "master", when I want to merge that feature branch into "develop" branch, commits B' and A' from "master" are also merged into "develop". Obviously they contain the same code than A and B, but git (and more specifically, GitHub) sees them as different commits and GitHub displays them as if they were doing real modifications to the code (but they are not).

This have two negative consequences:

1. I cannot trust what GitHub points out as modifications in the Pull Requests, which is inconvenient because I can no longer distinguish what are the real changes I am pushing to "master".
2. The commit history of the "develop" branch gets really messy.

Am I doing something wrong here or is there any other workflow I should be following in this situation?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that they *don't* necessarily contain the same code (they probably do in practice, but they really *are* different commits, so they do not have to match at all). To get the histories to align, so that the merge bases match up, you must actually merge the branches. As far as I know there are no non-messy, perfect solutions... (and, I have little practice in using GitHub's interface, I much prefer the command line interface, so I'm not sure what they do with these).

Comment: ...but unfortunately, I am almost never able to merge them (I would be carrying over unauthorized changes) :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workflow is correct.

1. When you push the changes to remote, if the new changes are not in the current branch on GitHub, it will show the **compare & pull request** button automatically. You can click the button, the detail changes at the bottom of the page. It doesn't matter if you are not used to merge branches by pull request on GitHub, its’s ok to merge branches by git command line (it’s really easier in most time).
2. You just confused that the commit B’ and A’ on master branch truly contains the same changes from commit A and B on develop branch. But **keep in mind this is not what git thought**, git treat every operation as a commit. Such as current commit is E, you modify a file, then the commit will be F, and you recover the file as original, the commit will be G. And git treat the commit E and G are the different things. So this is git’s manner to deal with every operation.

To check diff obviously, you can use `git diff branch1 branch2 --color > check.diff`.

Comment: I totally get what you point out, but then, I guess I have to live with the inconvenients I pointed out, and I find it really confusing: when doing a PR I will not be able to distinguish what real changes are done to the code vs. code that was already present :(

Comment: Yes, It's inconvenient to view the changes of Github pull request on VS. but there is a easier way if you try to distinguish changes by git command line.

Comment: Marina, you mean that git diff on the command line, for example, will show up real changes instead? I could work with that!

Comment: Yeah, that’s great! Check the different of branch1 and branch2, you can use `git diff branch1 branch2 > check.diff` or `git diff branch1 branch2 --color > check.diff` if you want different color. Then find the file in the directory when you use bash, it’s better to open the file with notepad++

Comment: @Mario_Exec.bat, hi, how it goes, Have you get want you want?

Comment: Hi @Marina, we've tried different options but I guess that checking with git diff is the best we can do. Could you please edit your answer and add that from your comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact reason [git-flow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) came into picture.

You can read more about the idealogy on http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

So according to this model, you will be creating `feature` branches from `develop` and merge it back in. For the non-sequential releases, you can use the `release` facility.

I wouldn't recommend this plugin if there are a lot of developers in the team as the git graph gets messier but for small teams its a game changer.

Comment: I am aware of git-flow, but couldn't adapt it to my needs: the "release" branch still contains sequential features (it is a snapshot of "develop" + bugfixes). And if I create a "release" branch by merging my feature branches, I will have the same problem I described (branching from "master" after merging "release" will carry the "release" commits back to "develop" when merging there for testing).